# Problema al hacer pedido a la base de datos

Tags: programación-bajo-nivel

Tengo la siguiente duda y error:

Disculpen que entre aquí a pedir ayuda pero no tengo otra opción. No se me permite aun un tema nuevo. Tengo la siguiente duda y error:

> En la pagina de procesamiento tengo:

```
    <?php
           $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","pruebadatos");
           mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
           $peticion="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE enlace=".$_GET['id'];
           $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$peticion);
           while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
              echo $fila["nombre"].'<br />';
              echo $fila["enlace"].'<br />';
              echo'<a href="productos.php?id='.$fila["enlace"].' ">ver mas</a><br /><br />';
           }
?>
```

Pero me da error. Sin embargo cuando cambio "enlace" por "id" y lo comparo con el id de la tabla no hay problema. Qué es lo que hago mal?

Lo que quiero hacer es que,  en mi url en vez que salga por ej: id=4, salga id=productoEjemplo ya que por "enlace" en mi base tengo el nombre de mi producto. Espero me entiendan Una vez lo hice pero no recuerdo como. Espero me puedan dar una manito Gracias

Comment: ¿Cuál y dónde sale el error, en el `$_GET['id']` o en `$fila["enlace"]` si es la primera no estás mandando el id a través de la url donde mandas llamar el archivo de php, si es el segundo tu tabla `productos` no tiene la columna enlace

Comment: Hola buenas tarde, por favor puedes colocar el mensaje de error que te esta generando así como esta pasando el valor del id por url. Gracias.

Comment: hola que tal muy amables por contestar, creo que no  me expreso bien por la ansiedad al escribir: bueno, tengo una tabla productos en la que tengo una columna "enlace" donde tengo por nombre similares a mis productos para mejorar la lectura de la url, yo hago el pedido de la siguiente manera:

Comment: Hola @jofret bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, te invito a que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que aprendas a elaborar tus preguntas correctamente y sean bien recibidas por los miembros de la comunidad.

Comment: hola que tal muy amables por contestar,  bueno, tengo una tabla productos en la que tengo una columna "enlace" donde tengo por nombre similares a mis productos para mejorar la lectura de la url, en el primer grupo de codigo envío productos.php?id='.$fila["enlace"].   y recibo  la variable id y la comparo asi: $peticion="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE enlace=".$_GET['id']; pero me da error no me da ningun resultado

Comment: `enlace` es un string? En dado caso te faltan las comillas en tu query: `WHERE enlace='".$_GET_['id']."';`

Comment: ¿te da error? ¿o no obtienes resultado? si hay error, aun no has dicho cual es el mensaje de error.

Comment: Graciass!!!!!!!!, si faltaban las comillas, aunque me hicieron sufrir un poquillo más tenia que hacer la peticion asi: $peticion="SELECT * FROM productos WHERE enlace='".$_GET['id']."'";           ------------------------ Excelente foro!!